# Unexpected height of li element in jquery sortable plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, column-count

I have used this plugin and it works great but one small bug I am facing is that li element gets unexpected height. You can replicate issue by following steps:
1. Open  [sortable demo](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default) in Internet Explorer and inspect on ul list.
2. From developer tools css add below css to  **'#sortable'** to divide this list in 2 columns

```
column-count: 2;
-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
column-gap: 0em;
-moz-column-gap: 0em;
-webkit-column-gap: 0em;
```

3. now observe that 4th element got divided by half on each side, try dragging the 4th item in list and observe height of li element

Link to sortable plugin: [jQuery-ui-Sortable Demo](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default)

Hoping for quick fix for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sortable li {
   break-inside: avoid;
}
```

adding break-inside to li solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to give css to the "li" element inside "#sortable" to divide the list into 2 columns.
Example :

```
#sortable li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Give width to "li" accordingly.

Comment: Hey Manpreet, Thanks for your time and suggestion. I have tried that way but unfortunately then list comes as 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 in this sequence one beside other so in sorting the left right li get shuffled, instead i need a effect like user is searching vertically not horizontally. Anything that we can do with column-count?